# How to find the distance between two parallel lines?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I'm trying to solve the following problem. I'm given few sticks of length [42, 40, 32, 30, 25, 18, 15] in this case. I'm able to construct three valid combinations of triangle. Now I need to calculate the distance between the lines (ie' the width occupied by all the triangles). One thing which strikes me is to find the height of each triangle - but I'm not able to proceed further.

[image]

Some clue on this would be helpful please.

Comment: It is not clear what distance you mean. No parallel lines here. What is the 'width' of a triangle? Perhaps [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) may help.

Comment: @ajotatxe: Sorry for not being clear. I've highlighted the parallel lines here.

Comment: You need more information like the angles. You can't proceed without it.

Comment: When we have the length of three sides of the triangle is it possible for me to find angle by someway?

Comment: @Mann One can calculate angles by the cosine formula if the lengths of sides are given

Comment: Hmm yes.. By using cosine formula I will be able to find the angles https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-sss-triangles.html

Comment: When I know the angles and when I know the sides of the triangle - how to find the distance between the lines in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the angles of triangles using the cosine rule, hence work out the distance of your point from the given line.

For example, in the left diagram, the triangle 25-30-32 the angle opposite 30 is
$$
\cos^{-1}\frac{25^2+32^2-30^2}{2\cdot 25\cdot 32}
$$
Similarly, the angle opposite 15 in 32-15-42 is
$$
\cos^{-1}\frac{32^2+42^2-15^2}{2\cdot 32\cdot 42}
$$
so the distance of vertex 15-42 from line 25 is
$$
42\sin\left(\cos^{-1}\frac{25^2+32^2-30^2}{2\cdot 25\cdot 32}
-\cos^{-1}\frac{32^2+42^2-15^2}{2\cdot 32\cdot 42}
\right).
$$

Comment: This is helpful thank you @user10354138.

Comment: Out of topic but curious to know - Which editor would you use when composing the text with formulas like the above?

Comment: Using the on-site editor is enough for this purpose, unless needing to do search-and-replace (or wanting to avoid accidentally deleting whole paragraph while editing), in which case I open a dedicated frame on Emacs.

Comment: I'm not clear with the sin approach. Can you explain me a bit more please? Why do we do a diff between the computed angles? What's the logic being applied here?

Comment: And how this would work with the right sided one?

Comment: We want to find the angle between the 42 side and the 25 side, which we go by the two triangles indicated.  For the right hand diagram, do it in two stages.  First find the distance from left line to one of the middle vertex, then do the second side to reach the vertex we want.

Comment: But why do angle between 42 side and the 25 side is required? I'm asking this because why we didn't calculate the height of triangle [30,25,32] alone without bothering about the other one...